# How to use map and split to parse a text file with python?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a RDD that has data that looks like this:

```
[‘ID: <166.1079>\nDate: 7 Dec 2010 16:06:42\nOwner: Mary Jones\nLab-Techs: Bob Chandra\nHarry Alley\n Julie Stevens\nNotes: West Position\nTemp: 1.0 C\nX-FileName:  temp-g\nX-Storage:  3544-ABC
X-Location: Building-A’]
```

It's a lab record, a text file. I have this python code that is not working correctly.  It is not splitting the fields properly and then taking each field and placing them in their respected RDDs.  Here is the code:

```
lab_data = sc.textFile('data_file')
fields = lab_data.map(lambda x: x.split('Notes:')(0).split('\n')
ID_field = fields(0).map(lambda x: x.split(':')(1).trim())
date_field = fields(1).map(lambda x: x.split(':')(1).trim())
owner_field = fields(2).map(lambda x: x.split(':')(1).trim())
```

Basically, I tried to grab the top 3 fields like ID, Date and Owner, but leave out all other fields.  So, the field RDDs would have values like:

```
ID field = <166.1079>
Date field =  7 Dec 2010 16:06:42
Owner field =  Marry Jones
```

Can you help me correct the code?

Comment: Does your file literally have `[]` and smart quotes?

Comment: It's unclear how your input is formatted and what your desired output is. Do you want 3 `rdd`s or 1 with 3 fields? Have you considered using spark DataFrame instead?

Comment: The actual text does not have the [] and smart quotes, but when its read in with the textFile that is what the RDD shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse the string of the lab record in your list you can do:

#### Code:

```
data = dict(tuple(x.strip() for x in line.split(':', 1))
            for line in record.split('\n')[:3])
```

#### Test Code:

```
with open('file1', 'rU') as f:
    data = dict(tuple(x.strip() for x in line.split(':', 1))
                for line in f.readlines()[:3])
print(data)
```

#### file1:

```
ID: <166.1079>
Date: 7 Dec 2010 16:06:42
Owner: Mary Jones
Lab-Techs: Bob Chandra
Harry Alley
 Julie Stevens
Notes: West Position
Temp: 1.0 C
X-FileName:  temp-g
X-Storage:  3544-ABC
X-Location: Building-A
```

#### Results:

```
{'ID': '<166.1079>', 'Date': '7 Dec 2010 16:06:42', 'Owner': 'Mary Jones'}
```

Comment: OP is using [tag:pyspark] and reading data from hadoop- this code works for regular text files, but it won't solve his problem.

Comment: Thanks, using the dict is a good option.  This gets me closer to what I am looking for.